# Limit of the sequence ${\{(f(\frac{t}{n^{1/3}}))^n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume that f(x) is a function in $C^3([-1,1])$ such that $f(0)=1,$ $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$, and $f'''(0) = A \neq 0$. Fix $t \in [-1,1]$, and find the limit of the sequence ${\{(f(\frac{t}{n^{1/3}}))^n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

I'm not sure where to go with this one; calculating the derivative of the sequence seems like a bit of a nightmare.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: write $f(x)$ as its order-$3$ Taylor polynomial (at $x=0$) plus error term; and write $(1+y)^n$ as its order-$1$ Taylor polynomial (at $y=0$) plus error term. Does using these expressions to write $f(\frac t{n^{1/3}})^n$ make it easier to calculate the limit?

Comment: @GregMartin Here's my attempt at a solution: The Taylor series expansion for $f(x)$ is $1 + \frac{1}{6}Ax^3 + O(x^4)$. Plugging in $\frac{t}{n^(1/3)}$, I get $(1 + \frac{1}{6}A\frac{t^3}{n})$. Then, the Taylor expansion for $(1+y)^n$ is $1 + ny + \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)y^2 + ...$. So when I plug in I now get $f(\frac{t}{n^{1/2}})^n = 1 + \frac{1}{6}At^3 + ...$ where the higher order terms vanish as n goes to infinity. Is this close to correct?

Comment: Definitely the right procedure and answer! Handling the error terms is all you need to make it rigorous. $(1+y)^n = 1+ny+O(n^2y^2)$ will simplify that. (Also, note that you can check the answer with functions like $f(x)=Ax^3+1$ or, even better, $f(x) = e^{Ax^3/6}$.)